# Compare array properties in Cosmos DB (SQL API)

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

Suppose we have Cosmos DB documents of the following form:

```
{ "propA": [1, 2, 3], 
  "propB": [7, 2, 4, 2] }
```

Is it possible to write a query that returns all documents where at least one element in `propA` is a member of `propB` (in order words, where the two properties have a non-empty intersection)?

And if yes, is it also possible using LINQ (and the .NET Cosmos Client)?

Comment: Not sure on the query itself, but assuming you control the writing of the data, I'd try the route of computing this intersection fact and adding it as a boolean value on the document before writing. No problem querying for "intersects = true" :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try something like this sql:

```
SELECT distinct value c FROM c join d in c.propA where array_contains(c.propB,d)
```

Here is my result:

[image]

**LINQ:**

```
FeedIterator<Prop> setIterator = this.container.GetItemLinqQueryable<Prop>().SelectMany(prop => prop.propA.Where(e => prop.propB.Contains(e)).Select(e => prop).Distinct()).ToFeedIterator<Prop>();
```

Hope this can help you.